# Restrict Sweet Alert input characters Length in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Requirement : The user should not able to type more than 20 characters within the input box.

I have implemented Sweet alert for displaying messages in my Angular project.

Once we click on a button a sweet alert with input type password (popup) will be displayed

I need to restrict the password input to max length of 20

this should happen when the user types not after typing more than 20 characters and then restricting it.

```
Swal.fire({
    title: "Delete My Account",
    text: "Please enter your password to delete your account",
    input: 'password',
    allowOutsideClick: true,   
    showCloseButton: true,   
    inputAutoTrim:true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      if ((value).length > 20) {
        return 'You cannot enter more than 20 characters';
                }          
      else if (!value) {
        return 'Please enter the password';
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
          // console.log("Result: " + result.value);
          let password:any = result.value; 
          console.log(" (password).length : " + (password).length );
          if ((password).length > 20) {
            Swal.fire(  'Reached Max',  'You cannot enter more than 20 characters',  'error')
            return false;
        }

          this.userPassword = result.value;
          this.deleteMyAccount();            
      }
      else if (result.isConfirmed) 
      {
        Swal.fire(  'Password required',  'please enter the password',  'error')
      }
  });
```

The above code allows to add N characters to the input and then throwing an error message.

TIA

Comment: @GRD no it is firing, it fires after the user enters the password with N characters and  clicking on ok button but my requirement is the input should not allow user to add more than 20 characters

Comment: So, input is part of sweet-alert library or input is defined by you.

Comment: @GRD its a part of sweet-alert library

Answer (score 0):

You should use the maxlength="20" and onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==20) return false;" in the input tag.

input type="text" class="inputcustom" placeholder="Enter the bank account number" formControlName="accountNumber" maxlength="18" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==18) return false;">